# Continuous Date / Not continuous Date sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, sql-server-2012

I'm encountering a problem with continous date / not cointinuous date on sql server 2012.

I have a table that looks like this :

| Article | Creation date |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 04/01/2021 |
| 1234 | 05/01/2021 |
| 1234 | 06/01/2021 |
| 1234 | 07/01/2021 |
| 1234 | 10/01/2021 |
| 1234 | 12/01/2021 |
| 12345 | 02/01/2021 |
| 12345 | 03/01/2021 |
| 12345 | 17/01/2021 |
| 123456 | 01/01/2021 |
| 123456 | 03/01/2021 |
| 123456 | 05/01/2021 |

The problem is :
I want to get the count of every article by continuous date with the min date of the range, it's a bit difficult to explain what I want but there is an example of the result :

| Article | Creation date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 04/01/2021 | 4 |
| 1234 | 10/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 12/01/2021 | 1 |
| 12345 | 02/01/2021 | 2 |
| 12345 | 17/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 03/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 05/01/2021 | 1 |

For example :

- count of 1st row = 4 because there is 4 continous day on the range 04/01/2021 to 07/01/2021
- count of 2nd row = 1 because there is only 1 day, 0 continuous day with 10/01/2021 for this article
- count of 3rd row = 1 because there is only 1 day, 0 continuous day with 12/01/2021 for this article

I'm starting with that :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Article, [Creation date], StartDate= Dateadd(day,-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Creation date]),[Creation date])
    FROM  MyTable 
)
SELECT Article, min([Creation date]) as [Creation date], count(Article) as count 
FROM  CTE
GROUP BY StartDate, Article, [Creation date]
order by Article, [Creation date]
```

Output :

| Article | Creation date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 04/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 05/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 06/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 07/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 10/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1234 | 12/01/2021 | 1 |
| 12345 | 02/01/2021 | 1 |
| 12345 | 03/01/2021 | 1 |
| 12345 | 17/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 03/01/2021 | 1 |
| 123456 | 05/01/2021 | 1 |

but the result is wrong, I don't really know how to approach this problem. If someone can enlighten me, appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution in this case is to subtract an increasing sequence of values and aggregate.  This works because the difference is constant for incremental dates:

```
select article, min(creation_date), max(creation_date), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by article order by creation_date) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
group by article, dateadd(day, -seqnum, creation_date)
order by article, min(creation_date);
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it works really well. I didn't know this concept of gaps-and-islands problem. I will deepen this concept. Thank you again